# function to check argc and argv cs50

Tags: c, cs50

Trying to write function that will check agrc == 2 , argv[1] not negative and there is only digits in argv[1] , else main program just wont run and we type smth like " Error! Usage: ./code key"
So if we type ./code -1 or ./code 123 gdf or ./code 123sdf we will face error message and main programm wont work, but if we type ./code 123 we good and program work further.

```
int validkey(int argc, string y)
{   

    int yl = strlen(y);

    if (argc == 2 && atoi(y) > 0) //atoi coverts string into int
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < yl; i++)
        {
            if (isdigit(y[i]))
                {
                printf("we good\n");
                return 0;
                }
            else
                {
                printf("Usage: ./code key\n");
                return 1;
                }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./code key\n");
        return 1;
    }
return 0;
}
```

so in main program we have smth like this
`if (validkey(argc,argv[1]))` and main code goes on.
But this function dont work AT ALL it dont break main code no matter what we type(return 1; should brake it?), and if we type ./code 123ads it will pass the check and will return 0;
What i did wrong?

Comment: In C there is no primitive type string. How do you defined this type?

Comment: `return 1` is an exit point from a function, not a program. Do you mean `exit(1)`?

Comment: Try moving `printf("we good\n");
                return 0;` to after the `for()` loop.  `atoi(y) > 0` --> `atoi(y) >= 0`

Comment: `argc == 2` test before `int yl = strlen(y);`.  Perhaps more issues.  Better to post a [mcve].

Comment: @CRM: In the cs50 course material, `string` is a typedef to `char *` in order to "make things easier".

Comment: @MOehm Good to know. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: `atoi coverts string into int`  No, `atoi()` converts **everything** into an `int`, even things that aren't integers.  `atoi()` has no way to indicate an error, so you should **never** use it.  Use something like `strtol()` or `sscanf()` instead, and check the return values for errors.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i understend what was wrong, first better to solve tihs problem with `bool` not `int`
second  important to understend how to loop work. Its check `y[i]` and if this is `true` so if `y[0]` is digit loop wont go futher dont check `y[1] y[2]` etc, its stops and `returns 0`, so if we type 2d3d loop will check `y[0]` its 2 so its digit so we good and returns 0 and not cheking y[1] ... etc. so my noob solution is add another  int veriable `counter = 0` for exaple and

```
if(isdigit(y[i]))
{
    coounter++;
    if (counter == yl)
    {
        printf("we good\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

so final variant:

```
// check_the_key(argc, argv[1])
bool check_the_key(int argc, string argv)
{
    // atoi coverts string into int
    int key = atoi(argv);
    if (argc == 2 && key > 0)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int lenv = strlen(argv);
        for (int i = 0; i < lenv; i++)
        {
            if (isdigit(argv[i]))
            {
                counter++;
            }
            if (lenv == counter)
            {
                printf("we good\n");
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return false;
}
```